# Oracle dynamic pivot SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
id int,
fiber varchar2(40),
pct int);

insert into tbl (id, fiber, pct) values ('1','Cotton','60');
insert into tbl (id, fiber, pct) values ('1','Poly','40');
insert into tbl (id, fiber, pct) values ('2','Elastane','30');
insert into tbl (id, fiber, pct) values ('2','Cotton','50');
insert into tbl (id, fiber, pct) values ('2','Spandex','20');
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query with PIVOT to put these into columns, so my SQL result looks something like this:

```
ID  Fiber1   Pct1   Fiber2   Pct2   Fiber3   Pct3
-------------------------------------------------
1   Cotton   60     Poly     40
2   Elastane 30     Cotton   50     Spandex  20
```

I've never used Pivot before.  All of the examples I found have the columns explicitly listed out in the Pivot query.  The problem is, the fiber column has dozens of different values, so hard coding them in the query isn't practical.

Curious if there's a way to make the columns generic like this and get the data into rows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to number the rows for each `id` and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       "1_FIBER" AS fiber1,
       "1_PCT" AS pct1,
       "2_FIBER" AS fiber2,
       "2_PCT" AS pct2,
       "3_FIBER" AS fiber3,
       "3_PCT" AS pct3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY fiber) AS rn
  FROM   tbl t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(fiber) AS fiber,
  MAX(pct) AS pct
  FOR rn IN (1, 2, 3) 
)
```

Or, use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN fiber END) AS fiber1,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN pct END) AS pct1,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN fiber END) AS fiber2,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN pct END) AS pct2,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN fiber END) AS fiber3,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN pct END) AS pct3
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY fiber) AS rn
  FROM   tbl t
)
GROUP BY id;
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| ID | FIBER1 | PCT1 | FIBER2 | PCT2 | FIBER3 | PCT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cotton | 60 | Poly | 40 | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | Cotton | 50 | Elastane | 30 | Spandex | 20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gQhsyfss)

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()` to generate row number for every row, then use the conditional aggregation using `group by`, `max()` and `case` clause as follows :

```
with cte as (
  select ID, FIBER, PCT, row_number() over (partition by ID order by null) as rn 
  from tbl
)
select ID, max(case when rn = 1 then FIBER END) as fiber1,
           max(case when rn = 1 then PCT END) as Pct1,
           max(case when rn = 2 then FIBER END) as Fiber2,
           max(case when rn = 2 then PCT END) as Pct2,
           max(case when rn = 3 then FIBER END) as Fiber3,
           max(case when rn = 3 then PCT END) as Pct3
from cte
group by ID;
```

If you are interested by ordering your data in row level then you can `order by fiber` or other(s) columns

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cW854Nuy)